# Can the Arduino Micro power the five volt and three volt pins at the sime time?

Tags: arduino

I have an arduino micro and I require to power two 3v motors of it. I am using the 5v for one motor and the 3v for the other motor. The problem is that I do not get a 3v voltage coming from the 3v pin.
Is this normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arduino micro does power the 3.3V and 5V at the same time.

However, these outputs tap into the onboard regulators which are in the mW range!
This means that plugging anything there beyond a handful of leds will definitely put the supply down!

You should use and external regulator for each motor, such as a LM7805C for the 5V rail and a LD1117AV33 for the 3.3V which are dead simple to wire (but do not forget the capacitors on each pin as per the spec).

Comment: Yea, I also realized that the USB also supplies a certain voltage. I am now using an external power supply.